# What was the important thing Clara said to the Doctor in the cloisters?

Tags: doctor-who

In *Hell Bent*, when Clara was talking to the Doctor about being trapped in the confession dial:

> CLARA: No. Why would you even do that? I was dead! I was dead and gone. Why? Why would you even do that to yourself?
>   DOCTOR: I had a duty of care. Listen, I'm nearly through here. *[burble, clang]* If I'm right, there should be a service duct under here. We'll be able to get to the old workshops. They'll have TARDISes there.
>   CLARA: Okay, listen. I have something I need to say.
>   DOCTOR: We do not have time.
>   CLARA: No, my time, my time is up. Doctor, between one heartbeat and the last is all the time I have. People like me and you, we should say things to one another. And I'm going to say them now.

But the screen panned out, so we don't know what she said now, which is not cool. What could it be? I thought it was a speech the 11th Doctor said, but what was the "very important" message she gave him in the cloisters?

Comment: "Don't worry, Doctor. They'll be watching me"

Comment: I took the liberty of replacing your rough quotes by exact quotes from the episode transcript - hope you don't mind!

Comment: @tilley31 I'm pretty sure this is the correct answer (if it is flashed out a bit), and you should probably post it as such, so that OP can accept...

Comment: @tilley31 that's only part of it, the rest we do not know. As the question explicitly asks "what do you think", this should be closed as opinion-based until such time as a writer decides what she said and that we should know.

Answer (score 13):

### We don't know.

From the episode transcript (emphasis mine):

> OHILA: What did you say to him?
>   CLARA: Oh, nothing I'm going to tell you, or anybody else. Except maybe this one part. I said: **Don't worry, Doctor. They'll all be looking at me**.

And much later, after the Doctor has lost his memories of her:

> CLARA: What Clara told you in the Cloisters ...
>   DOCTOR: I don't remember a single thing about it.
>   CLARA: You said memories become stories when we forget them. Maybe some of them become songs.
>   (He turns away and continues playing.)
>   DOCTOR: That would be nice.

The whole point of Clara saying something to him and the camera moving away to pan across the city was that **we're not supposed to know what she said**. Whatever it was, it must have been something deep and personal between the two of them. We only know nine words of it (assuming she wasn't lying about those nine words), and as for the rest, Clara is now the only person in the universe who knows what she said.

It's *possible* this could be revealed and used as a plot point in a later episode (a la [the Doctor's hand](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Tenth_Doctor's_hand)), but since Clara and the Doctor are meant never to meet again and Jenna Coleman has left the show, this seems highly unlikely. It looks like **it will always be a mystery**.

Comment: can you edit this it makes no sense like It's possible this could be revealed and used as a plot point in a later episode (a la the Doctor's hand),  please

Comment: @user63430 Think of all the excitement that hand went through. In the 2005 Christmas special, it looked like just a throwaway thing that we'd never see again; in the series 3 finale, it resurfaced to be used as a weapon against the Doctor; and then in the series 4 finale, it was used to create a whole new Doctor! This kind of thing happens a lot in Doctor Who: **some apparently insignificant object or event later turns out to have massive importance for the plot**. What I was saying here was that Clara's words to the Doctor *could* turn out to be one of those things, but I doubt it.

Comment: oh sorry why are you comparing what Clara said to the Doctor in the cloisters" and "the Tenth Doctor's hand" that got cut off and grew the meta crisis 10th doctor and what is the former also being an instance of this

Comment: @user63430 **Sometimes in Doctor Who, something that appears in one episode and is quickly forgotten crops up again much later and has some massive significance.** The Doctor's hand is an instance of this (appeared in the 2005 Christmas special, was quickly forgotten, cropped up again in Series 3 and 4, was very significant). I was raising the possibility that Clara's words in the cloisters could be another instance (appeared in the Series 9 finale, quickly forgotten, crop up again in 3 years' time, become very significant), but then discarded that possibility.

Comment: oh and when you said but since Clara and the Doctor are meant never to meet again and Jenna Coleman has left the show, this seems highly unlikely. It looks like it will always be a mystery. that could be true but she could come back as a echo like oswin and clara from londen or they meet up in a series 10 episode and his memory is back and they travele again through time and space and that will make me happy

Answer (score 0):

This is just a theory, but maybe she told the Doctor that she loved him. First of all, Clara makes it sound like it's something that's really important.

> CLARA: People like me and you, we should say things to one another. And I'm
> going to say them now.

What does she mean by "people like you and me?"

Their relationship has always seemed borderline romantic, and this season certainly didn't shy away. I'm not going to list every quote, but this one from Before The Flood seems to do the job,

> CLARA: If you love me, in any way, you'll come back.

(btw, he came back). There's also my personal favorite from this episode,

> CLARA: I was dead and gone! Why would you even do that to yourself?
>
> DOCTOR: I had a duty of care.

Now let's put that into context. The Doctor spent four-and-a-half billion years chiseling at azbantium in hopes of saving Clara (who, mind you, had died billions of years ago).

Her death was an established historical event and shouldn't have been altered. It could fracture time itself. The Doctor has always followed the Rules of Time close enough. When Amy and Rory were stuck in the past in The Angels Take Manhattan, he didn't try to save them. Sure, he was devastated, but he didn't want to risk fracturing time.

With Clara, the Doctor did the equivalent of saying "screw the rules." He tried to save Clara. He shot the General. He behaved irrationally. Emotionally.

I think this moment at the diner puts it well,

> CLARA: This Clara person, you must really like her.
>
> DOCTOR: Why do you say that?
>
> CLARA: You killed a man. You don't seem the type.

I believe he did this because he loved her. And I believe Clara felt the same way. I honestly can't think of anything else she could of possibly told him in the Cloisters; it's the only thing that fits.

Comment: Personally the absolute best scene in this episode was the look on Clara's face when the Dr. told her how long he'd spent inside that prison, taking the long way around.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Clara said that she loves him and I’m not saying this just because I ship them.

Before Danny died, Clara told him she loves him and that she'll never say it to anybody else. Then when Clara and Doctor sat in the Cloisters it seemed that something romantic will happen and when general asked Clara, what she told Doctor, Clara said that's something 'she'll never say to anybody else'.

Answer (score -1):

Or maybe she just explained her plan to him, and they thought she was saying something very important but that was just a trick to catch their attention to let the Doctor escape. I want this to be true because it's killing me not knowing what she actually said!

Comment: Maybe. Is there any evidence of this though, or is it speculation?

Answer (score -1):

Writing on blackboard was Claras whole thing in Heaven Sent, the self punishment that The Doctor endure for four and a half billion years just to have a chance to get Clara back. It would make a lot of sense to assume that the blackboard would have the final message from Clara to The Doctor. Maybe summarized.

Answer (score -2):

If it really is nine words maybe she said "Run you clever boy and remember, be a doctor". I've already counted and it's nine words plus there's this scene in Hell Bent where the blackboard had something written on it I'm pretty sure it said "Run you clever boy and remember be a doctor".

Comment: The words on the blackboard are "Run you clever boy and be a doctor". There is no indication that this was part of what Clara said in the Cloisters, and I doubt that it was.